# RESTful API Naming Resources & Controller design

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

Just reading through some RESTful API design best practices.  I am coming from an ASP.Net Web Forms background where I have been calling code behind WebMethods to return data to my client side javascript.  To me it seems logically to move these WebMethods out into an API so we can start centralizing and standardizing how we call back end systems.

I understand that the aim of REST is to categorize an operation on a resource to GET, POST, PUT and DELETE.  As well to use Nouns instead of Verbs for these resources.

1) 
So I have two methods that return data to produce reports.  I created their own respective Classes BreakdownIncidents and BreakdownMinutes due to client side binding and other specific properties to each report.

**[WebMethod] Top10MinutesBreakdowns**

```
|Machine|Department|Total Minutes|etc.|
```

**[WebMethod] Top10IncidentsBreakdowns**

```
|Machine|Department|Total Incidents|etc.|
```

Should these methods be organized:

```
GET /Breakdowns?report=minutes&type=top10
GET /Breakdowns?report=incidents&type=top10
```

Then in my Breakdowns controller check the parameters and call the appropriate existing business layer function to return the data?

2) The reports returns two different properties (simplicity sake: # of minutes and # of incidents).  Should I really be grouping these two methods into the same controller?

This is where I am confused because the report is using different properties but the underlying Object is a Breakdown.  Maybe this question is more suited for re-designing of my business object itself.  I am finding that our existing Business Layer has a lot of  classes that have been created for binding the client side views. I am sure there are more of these scenarios I will encounter as I try to build out this API.

Answer (score 0):

It's no problem to have both calls return a different resource. Just treat the report parameter as a sort of property filter. When you do not pass the report parameter, simply return both properties as part of the breakdown resource.

You could also include a fieldset parameter, making the returned properties more explicit, like: `/api/breakdown?fieldset=machine,department,minutes`.

If you have many reports with a great variety of properties per resource, you might consider something like [GraphQL](http://graphql.org/), which allows you to explicitly specify the properties for multiple resources to return in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that the aim of REST is to categorize an operation on a resource to GET, POST, PUT and DELETE. As well to use Nouns instead of Verbs for these resources.

Not really -- the goal of REST is the articulate the constraints necessary to support web scale applications.  See [Fielding, 2000](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm)

> This is where I am confused because the report is using different properties but the underlying Object is a Breakdown.

Don't confuse your API with your underlying implementations/representations.  The fact that the Top10MinutesBreakdowns and Top10IncidentsBreakdowns *information resources* happen to use references to the same underlying object is an accident of your current implementation.

In other words, your controller(s) are adapters, supporting the illusion is just a document store that understands HTTP request messages.

Choosing to support those two reports in the same controller, or different controllers, really depends on things like how often those reports change relative to each other, the costs of customizing your routing of requests to the appropriate controller, and so on.

Any URI spelling that you can route correctly is fine, but I personally would be inclined to give these reports identifiers of their own.

```
GET /Top10MinutesBreakdowns
GET /Top10IncidentsBreakdowns
```

And then configure your routing to deliver those requests to the appropriate controller.